# Get time difference between all consecutive rows (latest one not printing)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to retrieve all columns data along with the time difference between all consecutive rows from the following table, where (sender_id = 1 OR = 2) and (recipient_id = 2 OR = 1).

```
CREATE TABLE records (
    id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    send_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    sender_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    recipient_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO records (send_date, content, sender_id, recipient_id) VALUES
('2013-08-23 14:50:00', 'record 1/5', 1, 2),
('2013-08-23 14:51:00', 'record 2/5', 2, 1),
('2013-08-23 15:50:00', 'record 3/5', 2, 1),
('2013-08-23 15:50:13', 'record 4/5', 1, 2),
('2013-08-23 16:50:00', 'record 5/5', 1, 2);
```

Problem is my select query won't output the latest record because of the WHERE clause :

```
SELECT t1.content, DATE_FORMAT(t1.send_date, '%b, %D, %H:%i') AS 'pprint_date', 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t1.send_date, t2.send_date) AS 'duration' 
FROM records t1, records t2 
WHERE (t1.id = t2.id - 1) /*<= this subtraction excludes latest record*/
  AND ((t1.sender_id = 1 AND t1.recipient_id = 2) 
   OR (t1.sender_id = 2 AND t1.recipient_id = 1))
ORDER BY t1.id ASC
```

How can I properly get the time difference between all consecutive records while still printing all of them ?

Comment: Edit your question and provide expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a correlated subquery:

```
select r.*,
       (select r2.send_date
        from records r2
        where (r2.sender_id in (1, 2) or r2.recipient_id in (1, 2)) and
              r2.send_date > r.send_date
        order by r2.send_date asc
        limit 1
       ) as next_send_date
from records r
where r.sender_id in (1, 2) or r.recipient_id in (1, 2);
```

You can get the duration (instead of the next time) by using `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, r.send_date, r2.send_date)` in the subquery.  I think the first version is easier for you to test with to see what is happening.

Comment: Your query works perfectly, I just had to add parenthesis in the where clause to prevent `next_send_date` to always be the first record date. Thank you !